# react set state isn't working immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I was making a function based react component and needed to set state with buttons but soon realised that setstate is working poorly here is the code I used:

```
function Test() {
    const [index, setindex] = useState(0)
    function next() {
        console.log(index);
        setindex(1)
        console.log(index);
    }
    function pre() {
        console.log(index);
        setindex(-1)
        console.log(index);
    }
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={next}>next</button>
        <button onClick={pre}>previous</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

console shows that index is the same before and after it's set and it also set with a delay of one button press. I know that I can do that using radio buttons because they work fine for some reason but it seems like a bad solution. Can you please tell me why it behaves like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) is asynchronous in nature. if won't reflect immediately as you're expecting.

If you need anything after state is been changed use `useEffect` like :

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(index === 'blah') { // your value here 
     console.log(index)
   }
}, [index]);
```

or you can use callback like this :

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```